# Перевод "code fences" в справке по Markdown

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

В [справке по Markdown](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) не переведено

> Instead of using indentation, you can also create code blocks by using “code fences”, consisting of three or more backticks or tildes

Строка есть в Traducir, но непонятно, как переводить "code fences". Термин редкий, помимо SO встречается только на Github, у которого нет русского интерфейса.

Comment: А обязательно эту фразу переводить? Можно просто опустить)

Comment: "Границы кода" можно было бы использовать, кмк.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/11176

Добавил вариант:

> Вместо использования отступов, вы также можете выделять код, обрамляя
>   его тремя и более обратными кавычками или тильдами:

Comment: утвердил-дил-дил идёт ...

Comment: Вижу совершенно другой текст: _"Для создания фрагментов кода или другого предформатированного текста используйте отступ в 4 пробела или выделение группами обратных апострофов с обеих сторон:",_ в котором, кстати, ничего не сказано, что апострофов должно быть хотя бы 3.

Comment: @Qwertiy https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUstb.jpg

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ясно, не там смотрю: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7yxR.png